# Stationing Callouts using VBScript Labeling in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, vbscript

I have a shapefile that I'm trying to produce a specific label for using VBScript. I'm using the values in the [MEASURE] field.

`"PI: " & INT([MEASURE]/100) & "+" & (ROUND(([MEASURE] - INT([MEASURE]))*100,2))`

**MEASURE = 33598.2794**

Current Output = PI: 335+27.94

Desired Output = PI: 335+98.28

How do I change the VBScript I currently have In ArcMap to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtract the `INT([MEASURE]/100)` value, multiplied by 100, from the `MEASURE` to leave the remaining `98.28`

Use Advanced label expression

```
Function FindLabel ( [MEASURE] )
 DIM leftval, rightval
 leftval = INT([MEASURE]/100)
 rightval = ROUND([MEASURE]-(leftval*100),2)

 FindLabel = leftval & "+" & rightval
End Function
```

[image]

Basically subtracting 33500 from 33598.28, leaving 98.28 which is then appended to the label

[image]

Can also do it in a simple expression but it's a little harder to read and debug

```
INT([MEASURE]/100) & "+" & ROUND([MEASURE]-(INT([MEASURE]/100)*100),2)
```